# Why do flights sometimes share the same flight numbers?

Tags: air-travel

Flights sharing the same flight numbers can be confusing. Why do flights sometimes share the same flight numbers?

This means that one can find two flights that have the same flight number. Eg some airline might have one flight from x to y, another flight from a to b, and use the same flight number for both flights on the same date.

Comment: do you mean two flights by the same company, on the same day, under the same number?

Comment: @KristvanBesien yes but not necessarily on same day

Comment: A concrete example would help.

Comment: related https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/can-an-airline-schedule-two-same-number-flights-to-leave-the-same-airport-on-the/84884#84884

Comment: Edit does not clarify, at least dates and locations are needed.

Comment: @Willeke What is unclear in the "Why do flights sometimes share the same flight numbers?"?

Comment: No information at all.

Comment: @Willeke the question is clear to me and to the 2 answerers. So what's your issue with it?

Comment: The two answers answer a different question each, showing the question is unclear.

Comment: @Willeke they answer the same question but give two different reasons, which I've already stated in a comment

Comment: Personally I struggle to see how any "why" question about flight numbers falls within the site scope, i.e. a travel question "based on an actual problem that you face". You know *that* it happens, what problem is solved or mitigated for the traveller by learning *why*? That strikes me as an airline operations question of no relevance to the traveller, and as such something that belongs on aviation.se rather than here.

Comment: @ChrisH there are plenty of why questions on this website. I know this is hard to believe but some travelers prefer not to be clueless

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I suggested an alternative, more fitting, venue for the question. I don't know how you could interpret that as a suggestion you should simply "be clueless". Even if I hadn't: I know this may be hard for you to believe, but there are ways to find information that don't involve asking travel.SE.

Comment: Question reopened but only after adding 'date' .

Comment: I believe this is a dupe - have linked, but open to hearing why it's not, if it's not.

Comment: @MarkMayo not a dupe, the other question is about two planes can have the same flight number, whereas here I'm asking if two flights can have same flight number

Comment: Yeah. For all I've said about not thinking this question belongs here, it's clearly not a duplicate of the one it's now been linked to. This asks about multiple scheduled routes under the same flight number. The other asks about the same route being flown by different planes from one day to the next.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt agreed on re-reading, reopened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a finite number of flight designations, particularly as the legacy systems behind a good deal of scheduling and reservations are limited to a two-character airline code and a four-digit flight code (XX0000).

Over the last two decades there has been an extraordinary expansion of codeshare agreements, not just for regional carriers, but through inter-airline agreements and the global airline alliances. AA1 is not just AA1. It is simultaneously BA2430 and QF3100, and also QR7770 and TN1101, and also AT5034 and B64000. Those numbers come out of each of those carriers' "inventory" of available flight numbers.

There has also been considerable industry consolidation. Although most of the European carriers continue to operate separately, the North American carriers have opted to unify, so while the overall number of flights has probably decreased (I don't have the numbers in front of me, but capacity has been noticeably reduced over the last decade), there are fewer airline codes to split the designations among.

As a result, there has been a surge in demand for flight numbers, and scheduling two flights with the same number is one way an airline can "conserve" them. Short regional flights from a hub, for example, might use the same number on the outbound and the return.

It has long been possible that a delayed flight and the next day's flight might be operating at the same time, with the same origins and destinations, and in the same air traffic control sectors at the same time, and so operationally I expect there is a way of handling this, though I am not familiar with the details. But under regular operations, I don't think either the airline or its regulators would want to risk having two flights with the same number aloft in the same sector at the same time.

Comment: Add to that that codeshare flights, as well as flights operated by "regional subsidiaries" and whatnot, often have assigned flight number ranges, as those are used in fare rules (e.g. valid on all XY flights except XY4000-4999). This leads to a certain degree of waste if the ranges do not exactly match the number of flights in each range.

Comment: `operationally I expect there is a way of handling this, though I am not familiar with the details` - see [my answer to a similar question on aviation.se.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84886/54557)

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes its just a marketing trick.

Some airlines simply combine two arbitrary routes through a hub, give it the same flight number and the market it as a "direct flight" from A to B.

Example: I booked a "direct flight" on United from Boston to Vegas and it turns out it had a stop in Denver. It was NOT the same plane, NOT the same crew, NOT the same gate. My outbound from Boston was delayed, our flight to Vegas had already left, so I had to spend the night in Denver.

So in this case the only difference between a "direct flight" and a normal connection was that both legs have the same flight number.

Comment: We seem to be answering two completely different questions.

Comment: @choster why do you say that? The two answers are different but answer the same question regarding the reuse of flight numbers.

Comment: One answer is answering the question, why one flightnumber is assigned to two "physical" flights, the other answer is answering, why one "physical" flight has two flightnumbers. Those are different questions with different reasonings.

Comment: @dunni both answers address why one flightnumber is assigned to two "physical" flights.